How can I redirect `prompt_toolkit` `prompt` output to standard error?
How can I redirect prompt_toolkit output to standard error?
I’m working with a script that uses from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import prompt, and I'm trying to display a progress bar to standard error instead of standard output. Here’s the core of my setup:
def get_prompt(self):
    num = 10
    cnt = int(self.pct * 10) if not np.isnan(self.pct) and self.pct >= self.threshold else 0
    bar = "#" * cnt + "_" * (num - cnt)
    bar = bar[:num]

    dur = time.time() - self.start_time
    return f"Recording. Press option and ENTER (or just ENTER for default)... {dur:.1f}sec {bar}"

choice = prompt(self.get_prompt, refresh_interval=0.1)

When using the prompt function, the progress bar output defaults to standard output, which isn't what I want. I tried specifying sys.stderr as the output but encountered an error when passing output=create_output(sys.stderr). I also tried using PromptSession and other tweaks, but I kept running into issues. Has anyone successfully redirected prompt_toolkit output to standard error?
What I Tried:

Using prompt() with output=create_output(sys.stderr)
My initial approach was to directly pass output=create_output(sys.stderr) to the prompt() function, hoping it would allow the output to go to standard error instead of standard output. Here’s what the code looked like:
import sys
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.output import create_output

# Attempt to direct output to standard error
stderr_output = create_output(sys.stderr)

def get_prompt():
    return "This should appear on stderr."

choice = prompt(get_prompt, output=stderr_output)

Result: This resulted in an error:
TypeError: prompt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output'

Explanation: I realized that prompt() doesn’t accept an output parameter directly, which meant I needed another approach to customize output streams.

Switching to PromptSession
Next, I discovered that PromptSession can accept an output parameter, so I tried using it instead of prompt(). Here’s what I did:
import sys
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.output import create_output

# Create a PromptSession with output to stderr
stderr_output = create_output(sys.stderr)
session = PromptSession(output=stderr_output)

def get_prompt():
    return "Recording to stderr session."

# Using the session to display output to stderr
choice = session.prompt(get_prompt)

Result: This seemed promising, but I encountered another issue. My environment threw an error due to vt100 imports, specifically when trying to use StderrOutput.
ImportError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.output.vt100'

Explanation: I realized that vt100-specific implementations like StderrOutput were causing compatibility issues in some environments, making it unreliable.



Answer:
The best approach for redirecting prompt_toolkit output to standard error involves using PromptSession with create_output(sys.stderr). Here’s how I resolved it after a series of attempts and some challenges with importing certain functions. Here’s the setup that worked for me:
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.output import create_output
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, pct, threshold):
        self.pct = pct
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.start_time = time.time()

    def get_prompt(self):
        num = 10
        cnt = int(self.pct * 10) if not np.isnan(self.pct) and self.pct >= self.threshold else 0
        bar = "#" * cnt + "_" * (num - cnt)
        bar = bar[:num]

        dur = time.time() - self.start_time
        return f"Recording. Press option and ENTER (or just ENTER for default)... {dur:.1f}sec {bar}"

# Create an output object that writes to standard error
stderr_output = create_output(sys.stderr)

# Create a PromptSession with the custom output
session = PromptSession(output=stderr_output)

# Example usage
my_instance = MyClass(pct=0.5, threshold=0.3)
choice = session.prompt(my_instance.get_prompt, refresh_interval=0.1)

Explanation of Challenges and Solution:

Initial Attempts: Initially, I used prompt() directly with an output=create_output(sys.stderr) argument, but prompt() does not accept output as a parameter. The alternative was to use PromptSession, which does support custom output streams.

Unexpected Imports: I also tried using vt100.StderrOutput, but this led to import errors in my environment. Using create_output(sys.stderr) directly was ultimately successful.

Final Solution: By creating a PromptSession with stderr_output as a custom output object, the progress bar and other prompt_toolkit outputs can be redirected to standard error.


This solution keeps the main prompt functionality intact while directing the output to standard error, useful for logging or debugging scenarios where standard output needs to remain uncluttered. You can find my working code here on GitHub.
Final Solution: Using create_output(sys.stderr) with PromptSession
After encountering these issues, I decided to simplify and go back to using create_output(sys.stderr) directly. This approach worked without needing vt100 or any environment-specific dependencies. Here’s the final code that successfully redirected prompt_toolkit output to standard error:
import sys
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.output import create_output

# Create an output object that writes to standard error
stderr_output = create_output(sys.stderr)

# Create a PromptSession with the custom output
session = PromptSession(output=stderr_output)

def get_prompt():
    return "Final working solution on stderr."

# Use the session to display output on stderr
choice = session.prompt(get_prompt)

Result: This final approach successfully displayed output to standard error without additional import errors.
What I Was Expecting:
I was looking for a way to use prompt_toolkit to display output to standard error instead of standard output, especially useful for logging and debugging scenarios. Initially, I expected to set sys.stderr as the output target within prompt() directly, but the final solution using PromptSession and create_output(sys.stderr) met my needs effectively.
